# Java socket server and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, actionscript-3, sockets

I'm writing socket server in java for my flash browser based game and i need to connect to mysql database. Is it possible to connect to mysql through socket server and send received data to connected flash clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, besides it's probably the most common way to connect to MySQL server - through a socket. I believe that the default port assigned to MySQL server is 3306, but you would need to check your configuration (my.cnf file [which may be found in various places in your system](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000)) if it's not.